# One click order alternative - slide to pay

Tags: mobile, android, ios, payment, error-prevention

The mobile application is able to store (securely) credit card details and users can pay small amount for some services with "one click" button (no confirmation).
There is a chance users click it unintentionally ([like here](https://www.abc2news.com/business/consumer/dont-waste-your-money/beware-the-catch-with-amazon-1-click-ordering)).

The payment is available on the service page only with details like service duration and user's location (required for price calculation).

We came with UX improvement:
Said button is replaced by a "slider button" (full width of mobile screen in portrait mode) with the text "Slide to pay $1.23" and the user is required to slide it completely from left to right.

```
(( o )   Slide to pay 1.23$    )
```

The amount to be paid is small - mostly around 50c to few dollars.
The UX is consistent for iOS, Android and (mobile) web client.

### Questions

1. Is there any other alternative to avoid unwanted one-click mistakes (except confirmation/popup)?
2. Is there any patent covering "slide to pay" pattern? I am aware of
   slide-to-unlock only.

Comment: The slide-to-pay is currently available for some products withint the Amazon mobile app - They have a large budget for UX research so it's possible that the slide is the best currently available solution. If you're worried about copying someone like Amazon then you could try a circle motion instead of a linear swipe - just as easy but even less likely to be made by accident

Answer (score 2):

I think you're interaction pattern of "Slide to Pay" is a good idea to prevent one click mistakes.

I'm not sure if there is a patent that prevents you from using this interaction style for payments, but I do know of an app that uses the same interaction to get a user to confirm a money transfer. https://www.slydepay.com.gh/

I have two concerns about "Slide to Pay"

1. It might be a new interaction pattern for your users to learn, since it has not been popularly used in this context. However, depending on your onboarding and other cues, initial learning might be easy.
2. Security, as more and more people use phones to make payments, the risk of security becomes larger. A slide is easy for a Kid / Unauthorized person to use.

Another alternative that comes to mind is using a Long Press.

Have the user long press on a circle, which then expands to cover a larger concentric circle. If the user presses the inner circle long enough for it to expand and reach the outer circle you go ahead and confirm payment. Although this pattern has the same limitations as I described above, it has the added advantage that the user has potentially a longer time to back out of the payment and doesn't need a complete slide. Some users, such as older people, or left-handed individuals are comfortable with a full width left to right swipe.

If you're working on Native Apps, you have the alternative of using the fingerprint sensor. With mobile pay becoming common, users are used to scanning their fingerprints to authorize money related transactions, and increasingly banking apps are using this as a replacement for passwords. This pattern provides you the most secure way of authorizing a payment (Most secure is subjective, but definitely the most common secure way).

Comment: I like the idea of the "longer press" to confirm. Then one can style it as they please, but it's a good interaction pattern in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

One click purchases doesn't necessarily mean an immediate transaction from the purchase button being clicked, it simply means the system and the purchaser accepts certain defaults from what you know about the person who is registered and carrying out the transaction.

For example, they are not changing their billing/delivery address, they are using their default payment option and the terms of the sale have been previously agreed or are assumed to be agreed at the point of sale.

As such, it is not diluting a one-click purchase to confirm that someone wishes to carry through such a payment, whether that is through a change of use and confirmation of the purchase button or another message on which they confirm the payment.

Both are equally valid, what they are introducing is a moment of pause, a tangible interaction to prevent accidental purchases, much like your slide to purchase idea, all are valid and a bit of testing would probably prove out the most desirable.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to have a double tap interaction on the Pay button.
Once to "activate" the button and another to pay.

You will need a clear message for both button states. 
Ex: "I want to pay" for the first state and "Pay" for the second.(this is just an example, clearly not the best)